# 2 simple rule for fraction

Tags: fractions

I am embarassed to ask this question, but when a fraction divides a number, the rule is:

$\dfrac{a}{\dfrac{b}{c}}$ it is supposed to be $\dfrac{a\cdot c}{b}$

$\dfrac{\dfrac{a}{b}}{c}$ it is supposed to be $\dfrac{a}{b\cdot c}$

Notice the bar for diving fraction is different, in the first fraction it is longer for $a$ and $b$, while in the second it is longer for $b$ and $c$

So which rule should I use? I thought division of a number means multiplying the inverse of that number, am I correct?

Comment: Writing such a thing, whose interpretation is based on millimetre differences in bar-length,  is an abomination. If you really must, then write $$\frac{a}{b/c}$$ etc.

Comment: This reminds me of that stupid $8/4(2+2)$ thing on facebook

Comment: So which rule should I use?

Answer (score 1):

The longer bar means there are parentheses around the stuff above and below.  So $$\dfrac {\dfrac ab}{\dfrac cd}=\dfrac {\left(\frac ab\right)}{\left(\frac cd\right)}=\frac{ad}{bc}$$
where the middle bar is supposed to be longer in the first fraction.